# Logic Programming with Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

Logic Programming with Prolog:

Consider the program:

```
        f(X) :- !, X = a.
        f(X) :- !, X = b.
        f(X) :- X = c.
```

What does P return for the queries f(a) , f(b) and f(c) respectively?

Consider the program:

```
        f(X) :- X = a, !.
        f(X) :- X= b, !.
        f(X) :- X = c.
```

What does P return for the queries f(a) , f(b) and f(c) respectively?

Answer (score 1):

> What does P return for the queries f(a) , f(b) and f(c) respectively?
>
> ```
>   f(X) :- !, X = a.
>   f(X) :- !, X = b.
>   f(X) :- X = c.
> ```

```
?- f(a).
true.

?- f(b).
false.

?- f(c).
false.
```

> ```
>    f(X) :- X = a, !.
>    f(X) :- X = b, !.
>    f(X) :- X = c.
> ```

```
?- f(a).
true.

?- f(b).
true.

?- f(c).
true.
```